# survMisc::comp give incorrect p-value due to incorrect covariance matrix calculation

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I`m performing survival analysis on somewhat unusual data-set, which in raw form looks like this:

```
> print(df)
# A tibble: 407 × 4
   stress   len  time status
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1      0  5.32     1      1
 2      0  5.97     1      1
 3      0  4.08     1      1
 4      0  4.57     1      1
 5      0  6.11     1      1
 6      0  7.74     1      1
 7      0  5.55     1      1
 8      0  5.86     1      1
 9      0  6.01     1      1
10      0  4.86     1      1
# … with 397 more rows
```

It is seed germination time set, composed of 407 individual seeds, with variable *time* indicating day at which seed germinated (day 1 to 7), variable *status* indicating event status (1 - germinated, 0 - censored) and variable *stress* indicating whether or not stressing treatment was applied to the seed (1 - applied, 0 - not applied), variable *len* isn't used.

It is treated as right-censored data and does not follow PH assumption. When passed to survMisc::ten() it looks like this:

```
> df_ten <- ten(Surv(time,status)~stress,data=df)
> as.data.frame(df_ten)
   t  e   n cg ncg
1  1 52 407  1 200
2  2 44 335  1 148
3  3 51 236  1 104
4  4 20 127  1  53
5  5 15  69  1  32
6  6  2  42  1  17
7  7  6  29  1  15
8  1 20 407  2 207
9  2 55 335  2 187
10 3 58 236  2 132
11 4 37 127  2  74
12 5 12  69  2  37
13 6 11  42  2  25
14 7  2  29  2  14
```

I wanted to compare survival curves using log-rank test and its different weighted modifications. Simple log-rank test can be done by using survival::survdiff(), but survMisc::comp() additionally performs calculation of its weighted modifications. However I found out that survdiff() and comp() give different p-values for log-rank.

Example:

```
> survdiff(Surv(time,status)~stress,df)
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ stress, data = df)

           N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
stress=0 200      190      173      1.70      4.72
stress=1 207      195      212      1.38      4.72

 Chisq= 4.7  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.03
```

survdiff gives p=0.03

```
>comp(df_ten)
# new R version have some troubles with displaying comp() results so I include them like this

> as.data.frame(attr(df_ten,'lrt'))
           W             Q          Var           Z       pNorm       chiSq df      pChisq
1          1   -17.1389764 7.788363e+01 -1.94205613 0.052130305 3.771582025  1 0.052130305
2          n -7159.0000000 6.365017e+06 -2.83760918 0.004545280 8.052025835  1 0.004545280
3      sqrtN  -352.4452268 2.030262e+04 -2.47352082 0.013378901 6.118305256  1 0.013378901
4         S1   -14.2339087 2.040569e+01 -3.15100126 0.001627118 9.928808966  1 0.001627118
5         S2   -14.1996105 2.028548e+01 -3.15270847 0.001617633 9.939570710  1 0.001617633
6 FH_p=1_q=1    -0.1198792 2.298284e+00 -0.07907548 0.936972583 0.006252932  1 0.936972583
```

But comp gives p=0.052

survdiff() result is actually the correct one and comp() is incorrect. I was able to figure out that it`s happening due to incorrect covariance matrix calculation by survMisc::COV() which is used within comp().

Again, example:

```
> survdiff(Surv(time,status)~stress,df)$var
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,]  62.17916 -62.17916
[2,] -62.17916  62.17916
```

This is correct value of VAR(Oi-Ei)=62.2, I was able to obtain the same result by calculating it manually using formula from Kleinbaum and Klein book.

```
> COV(df_ten)[COV(df_ten)>0]
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
16.128233 20.824661 20.724324 10.556427  5.463805  2.473937  1.712247
```

But COV() give incorrect one, when summed up it will give value of 77.83, which is then used by comp().

I still can obtain correct matrix value from COV() by giving it different ten format, but it can`t be used in comp().

```
> df_wide <- asWide(df_ten)
> as.data.frame(df_wide)
  t   n   e n_1 e_1 n_2 e_2
1 1 407  72 200  52 207  20
2 2 335  99 148  44 187  55
3 3 236 109 104  51 132  58
4 4 127  57  53  20  74  37
5 5  69  27  32  15  37  12
6 6  42  13  17   2  25  11
7 7  29   8  15   6  14   2
> rowSums(df_wide[,COV(x=e, n=n, ncg=matrix(data=c(n_1, n_2), ncol=2))],dims=2)
          1         2
1  62.17916 -62.17916
2 -62.17916  62.17916
```

I assume this have something to do with properties of my data-set, like specifically with the number of events per time point or with relatively small amount of time points and with formula internally used by COV() to calculate value which is:

```
...
res2 <- x[, (ncg / n) * (1 - (ncg / n)) * ((n - e) / (n - 1)) * e, by=list(t, cg)]
        res2 <- data.table::setkey(res2[, sum(V1), by=t], t)
...
```

[full function code here](https://github.com/cran/survMisc/blob/master/R/COV.R)

I have tried this stuff with different survival datasets in R, and it doesn`t seem to affect larger ones, but in relatively small data-set like coin::ocarcinoma you can also see difference in covariance and corresponding log-test value calculated by survdiff/comp functions.

So is there any straightforward way to fix this issue with comp()? Like by restructuring my data-set somehow or perhaps by tweaking formula used in COV()?

Comment: I'd recommend you file a bug report for survMisc package at: https://github.com/dardisco/survMisc/issues.